# Redirecting all ip to maintenance page except some ips

Tags: apache, .htaccess, symfony

When releasing new versions of my `Symfony` project, I need to redirect all external ip addresses to a `maintenance.html` page (which lives into symfony web directory) using apache.

Here is the `virtualhost` file configuration I've created for this purpose but:

- When I go from an external ip I get `403 Forbidden`
- When I go from `localhost` I get the same `403 Forbidden`

> virtualhost file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myservername
    ServerAlias www.myservername
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /path/to/my/symfony/project/web

    RewriteEngine on
    # if request not coming from localhost
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !127.0.0.1
    # if request not maintenance.html page
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_URI} !/maintenance.html [NC]
    # if request not image
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif|ico) [NC]
    # if request not css file
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_URI} !\.(css) [NC]
    # Redirect to maintenance.html page
    RewriteRule .* /maintenance.html [R=302,L]

    <Directory /path/to/my/symfony/project/web>
        # Ignore .htaccess files
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/maintenance-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/maintenance-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

What am I doing wrong?

> Technologies versions

```
apache2 -v 2.4.7   (needs to work on 2.2 too)
```

Comment: mod_rewrite doesn’t know a `%{REMOTE_URI}` variable. Do you mean `%{REQUEST_URI}`?

Comment: :'''''''( yeaaaah that's my fault. thx, plese add an anwser so that I accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mod_rewrite doesn’t know a `%{REMOTE_URI}` variable. Probably you mean `%{REQUEST_URI}`.